# Mootools Form.Validate is not firing events

Tags: javascript, validation, mootools, mootools-events, mootools-more

I don't know why the `Form.Validate` Class is not firing the events when an input fails. This is a simple test I've made:

**HTML**

```
<form id="IndicatorIndexForm" action="">
    <input type="text" id="IndicatorKilometers" data-validators="minLength:10" name="data[Indicator][kilometers]"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Valider" class="">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var myForm = new Form.Validator($('IndicatorIndexForm'), {
    onFormValidate: function(resp,form,e){
        console.log('error');
    },
    elementFail: function(el,errors){
        console.log('elementFail');
        console.log(el);
        console.log(errors);
    },
    elementValidate: function(resp,el,validator,is_warning){
        console.log('elementValidate');
        console.log(resp);
        console.log(el);
        console.log(validator);
        console.log(is_warning);
    }
});
```

but when I submit the form, in the console I only see "error". If I understood correctly the documentation, it should also fire the other two functions... I feel that I'm forgetting something.. any ideas?

*here's the jsfiddle* http://jsfiddle.net/HJX3K/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. you are missing `on` prefix for the events:

```
var myForm = new Form.Validator($('IndicatorIndexForm'), {
    onFormValidate: function(resp,form,e){
        console.log('error');
    },
    onElementFail: function(el,errors){
        console.log('elementFail');
        console.log(el);
        console.log(errors);
    },
    onElementValidate: function(resp,el,validator,is_warning){
        console.log('elementValidate');
        console.log(resp);
        console.log(el);
        console.log(validator);
        console.log(is_warning);
    }
});
```

Comment: ._. ...It's like my teacher used to say: "when you have an error in js, 99% of the time is YOUR fault and not mootool's".. THANKS :)